# Obstruction to the existence of a deformation of a subvariety compatible with the given deformation of a variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a field $k$ of characteristic 0,
and let $A$ be a local Artinian $k$-algebra, say, $A=k\oplus I$
where $I$ is an ideal such that $I^2=0$.
Let $\frak X$ be a flat projective $A$-scheme such that ${\frak X}\times_A k=X$.

Let $Y\subset X$ be a $k$-subscheme, non necessarily smooth.
I wish to construct a flat $A$-subscheme $\frak Y\subset\frak X$
such that ${\frak Y}\times_A k=Y$.

> **Question.** What is the obstruction to the existence of such $\frak Y$, and where does this obstruction live?

Feel free to send this elementary question to Math. StackExchange.com

Comment: I performed this calculation about 40 years ago, but I don't remember the answer...

Comment: The obstruction space is $\mathrm{Ext}^2_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(\mathbb{L}^{Y/X},\mathcal{O}_Y\otimes_kI)$.

Comment: @JonPridham: Thank you! What is ${\Bbb L}^{Y/X}$ ?

Comment: The relative cotangent complex. When $Y$ is LCI, it's the shifted conormal bundle, but in general it's more complicated.

Comment: Actually, given that Hilb and Quot agree, another valid obstruction space is $\mathrm{Ext}^1_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{I}_Y, \mathcal{O}_Y\otimes_kI)$, which is probably easier to calculate.

Comment: Thank you! What is LCI ?

Comment: @JonPridham: Is $\mathcal{I}_Y$ the sheaf of ideals defining the subscheme $Y$ ?

Comment: LCI is local complete intersection, and $\mathcal{I}_Y$ the ideal sheaf.

Comment: @JonPridham: Many thanks for your very helpful comments! However, I, and also the MO community, would benefit from an *answer*!  Could you please kindly type an answer, when you have time?